# Regarding vba classes coded in Visual Studio VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to start coding my macros for Excel in Visual Studio, it needs changing some things but I think I'm ok as for normal modules go.

My question is, how do I code classes there?

When I try to code a new class it forces me an argument called `Of`:

```
Public Class FNMT(Of)
    Public Sub TratarDatos(arr As Object, Dict As Object)


    End Sub

End Class
```

And says it's expecting an identifier. How would classes work in Visual Studio? I couldn't use properties neither, it was saying that I can't use the Let/Get.

Can't find anything about this either here nor in google. Any insights?

This is how I'm writting the code:
[image: ID]

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure what are you telling me, but I'm using Visual Studio to write my macros.. Am I doing something wrong here? Added an image to clarify(or hope to clarify)

Comment: But can I use VB.Net to code macros for Excel, right?

Comment: @BigBen any good source to learn on my topic? wether it's video tutorials or just plain text.

Comment: VBA and VB.net are two different languages.  VBA is a hostable version of the old COM-based VB4/VB5, which COM-based Microsoft products like Excel, Word and Access host as their scripting and customization language.  These COM-based facilities do not know about .Net.  VB.net is the .Net-based re-implementation of VB.  While it shares a lot of syntactical features with VBA, they are very distinct languages and facilities.  What you *can* do is to implement COM objects using VB.Net and the COM-interop facilities that you can create and use from Excel/VBA.   ...

Comment: ... Also, you can use .Net's VSTO facilities to make VSTO packages for MS Office products like Excel.  You cannot, however, use Visual Studio for .Net to develop VBA (well, not in any practical way).

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-net-class-library-excel-vba-40349.html May shed some light. You can compile a .dll